# Call an event listener from angular 4 service

Tags: angular, service

Let's say I have a component like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',

  template: `
  <button class="btn btn-primary" 
  (click)="buttonClicked()">testbutton</button>`,

  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private testService : TestService) {
      // some code
    }
    buttonClicked(){
       console.log("clicked");
    }
}
```

Now, there is a service called TestService. Is it possible to add another event listener(clickEvent listener) to the same button in TestService?

I am trying add two event listeners, but one being in the component file, other in service file.

For example, it is possible if done in jquery like :

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
     console.log("button clicked outside of component");
}
```

Comment: Why does the event listener have to be in the service? You could have the `buttonClicked()` method call another method within the service. Therefore both methods trigger when the user clicks on the button

Answer (score -1):

**Update** Based on your Use Case comment, I don't think there's a good way to listen to every button click without modifying component files. The clearest design is to call the service's method from every click event.

The only other **hacky** way I know of is to put a click event on your app component element and use the passed $event to decide to log or not.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="template page-container" (click)="onClicked($event)">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
onClicked(e: any) {
  console.log(e);
  let pointerEvent = e as PointerEvent;
  if (pointerEvent) {
    let target = pointerEvent.target as HTMLButtonElement;
    if (target) {
      let isButtonClick = !target.disabled;
      if(isButtonClick) {
         //do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Original**
I don't know what your use case is for doing it, but Angular lets you call two methods for an event.

Edit: You should expose the private service in a public property so the template can access it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',

  template: `
  <button class="btn btn-primary" 
  (click)="buttonClicked(); myTestService.buttonClicked()">testbutton</button>`,

  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private testService : TestService) {
      // some code
    }

    get myTestService() {
       return this.testService;
    }

    buttonClicked(){
       console.log("clicked");
    }
}
```

Can you say why? There is probably a better way to do what you need.

Comment: So, my use case is, that I already have a working angular project with multiple modules, services etc.
I have to adding a functionality to all the events, for example lets say, I want to console print a message1 in all the event listeners. 
Obviously, one way of doing this would be adding this code block in every event listener. But, another way that I am trying to do here is to simply create a service and add more listeners in this separate file. So, there will be no code changes in other files.

Comment: Now, by using jquery i can do that like this :

 $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
     console.log("button clicked outside of component");
}

No code changes in the old event listeners. This is what i am trying to achieve in angular4

Comment: providing service to template is a bad, bad idea, it disimproves readability. better way is to provide third method like combinedClickListener() and call two desirable methods inside of it

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea, but that's what he asked. I'd like to offer a better solution to what he's doing.